# Session handling on Spring Boot with LDAP authentication for some users and LinkedIn API login for others

Tags: spring, rest, session, authentication, ldap

I'm developing a Java-based Web app for human resources departments. There are two types of users: HR experts and applicants. Experts log in via LDAP authentication while applicants log in via LinkedIn API.

How can I configure the sessions of these two types of users? Does Spring have a library for this? Right now, there is no session configuration on my project so an expert and an applicant can log in at the same time from the same computer.

Also, I need to be able to make changes on .html files as well based on what type of user is logged in at a time. For example: An "Apply!" button should be visible for users who logged in via LinkedIn and a "View applicants" button should be visible to experts who logged in via LDAP. If you could also tell me about how does Thymeleaf, Spring and the session handling method you'll recommend to me work together, that'd be great.

My LDAP authentication:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("applicants**").fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/job/**/applicants").fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
                .logout().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:8389/"), "dc=springframework,dc=org");
    }

}
```

LinkedIn login:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/connect")
public class LinkedInController {

    public static boolean connected = false;
    public static Applicant applicant;

    private static final String API_KEY = "xxxx";
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "xxxx";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8080/connect/done/";
    private static final String STATE = "xxxx";
    private static final String NETWORK_NAME = "LinkedIn";
    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(%s)";
    private static final String RESOURCE_FIELDS = "id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,maiden-name,headline," +
            "industry,summary,picture-url";

    private OAuth20Service service;
    private ApplicantService applicantService;

    @Autowired
    public LinkedInController(ApplicantService applicantService){
        this.applicantService = applicantService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public ModelAndView redirectToAuthorization (Model model) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // Replace these with your client id and secret
        service = new ServiceBuilder(API_KEY)
                .apiSecret(SECRET_KEY)
                .scope("r_basicprofile r_emailaddress")
                .callback(REDIRECT_URI)
                .state(STATE)
                .build(LinkedInApi20.instance());
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
        System.out.println("Auth. link:" + authorizationUrl);
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(authorizationUrl));
    }

    @GetMapping("/done")
    public ModelAndView getToken(@RequestParam("code") String code, @RequestParam("state") String state, Model model) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        if (state.equals(STATE)){
            connected = true;
            System.out.println("State correct.");
            final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = service.getAccessToken(code);
            final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, String.format(PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, RESOURCE_FIELDS));
            System.out.println(request.getUrl());
            request.addHeader("x-li-format", "json");
            request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-RU");
            service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
            final Response response = service.execute(request);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Applicant applicant = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Applicant.class);
            this.applicant = applicant;
            applicantService.persistNewApplicant(applicant);
        }
        model.addAttribute("success", LinkedInController.connected);
        model.addAttribute("applicant", LinkedInController.applicant);
        return new ModelAndView("connected.html");
    }


}
```

I'm using Spring Boot, IntelliJ, H2 database, LinkedIn API and LDAP.

Comment: You should split your question into multiple different ones, and also post some Code what you have tried so far for each.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic added some code. I didn't try anything yet for sessions configuration. I don't know where to start since tutorials on the internet don't have any examples of something similar to my case.

Comment: did u get an answer for this. I'm facing a similar problem